# Upper bound for the quality of an $abc$-triple

Tags: number-theory, real-analysis, analysis, diophantine-equations, asymptotics

A triple of positive integers $(a,b,c)$ is an $abc$-triple if $a$ and $b$ are coprime and $c = a + b$. Define the *quality* or *power* of an $abc$-triple as $P(a,b,c) = \frac{\log c}{\log \text{rad}(abc)}$, where $\text{rad}(k)$ denotes the product of distinct prime divisors of $k$.

One version of the $abc$-Conjecture is that for each $\varepsilon > 0$, there are finitely many $abc$-triples such that $P(a,b,c) > 1 + \varepsilon$.

There are finitely many known triples satisfying $P > 1.4$, the so called *good triples*,  and the largest (quality) is $P(2,3^{10} \cdot 109, 23^{5}) = 1.629911684 \dots$ (discovered by E. Reyssat).

This leads me to some questions:

**Question one:** Is there an upper bound for $P(a,b,c)$ simply in terms of $c$ and absolute constants (sharper than $\log_{2} c$)?

**Question two:** Is there an absolute upper bound for $P(a,b,c)$ so that no triple has higher quality?

**Best Answer:** If there were such a bound, then asymptotic FLT would be in hand. (Thanks Ace of Base on MathOverflow). The full answer and restatement of the question can be found [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/44308).

Comment: The same question was asked as http://mathoverflow.net/questions/44308 on mathoverflow.

Comment: Actually, I asked it on MO when I got no answers here.